# Is my character who worships Gruumsh more likely to speak Infernal, Celestial, or Abyssal?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, languages

I'm making a half-orc cleric that worships Gruumsh, and the half-orc knows how to speak the language that Gruumsh speaks (besides Common and Orc). Would he speak Celestial, Infernal, or Abyssal?

Comment: Related on [Alignments and the plane of Acheron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/149001)

Comment: Why did you even include celestial?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Abyssal or Infernal would be the more appropriate additional language

As a god, Gruumsh could speak [whatever language he wants](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206243/75095). If your character knew how to speak any language Gruumsh can speak, that would mean they can speak all of them. Unless your DM wants to allow your character to speak all languages, if you need to pick one secondary language, **Infernal** or **Abyssal** would be more reasonable picks than **Celestial**.

Gruumsh is the patron deity of orcs, and his *alignment* is given as Chaotic Evil (*PHB*, p. 296). This would make Abyssal the most probable language to use<sup>1</sup>, the language of the chaotic evil demons, all of which are at home in evil-aligned lower planes. The **[Tanarukk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17298-tanarukk)**, which is a demon orc (*Volo's Guide to Monsters*, p. 186) likewise speaks Abyssal, Common, and Orc.

[Gruumsh lives in Acheron.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#OrcsTheGodsworn) *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (p. 82):

> [...] the orcs know that if they fight well and bring glory to their tribe, Gruumsh will call them home to the plane of Acheron. It is there in the afterlife where the chosen ones will join Gruumsh and his armies [...]

Acheron is an eternal battleground between orcs and hobgoblins and Infernal would be common there. (Thanks to @[MattVincent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/33059/matt-vincent) for finding this; see [his answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206254/75095) for more detail).

In contrast, Celestial is the language of the celestials (such as angels), who are at home in good-aligned upper planes – much worse a fit. (See *PHB* page 123 for a list of [languages](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#Languages).)

---

<sup>1</sup> Older editions – starting from first edition – gave Gruumsh as lawful evil, with the Nine Hells as his home plane. That would make Infernal better, but this is not the case any more in 5e.

Comment: Is a Tanrukk an abherration/monstrosity created by Gruumsh(I don't have the stats)?

Comment: No, its created by demonic corruption: "When demonic corruption taints a tribe's leadership, ores might turn to abyssal magic to make tanarukks. Evil humans who control ores also use such power to bolster their followers' strength. The demon lord Baphomet gladly shares the secret of creating tanarukks with those who entreat him for
power."

Comment: @NautArch - see Thomas's answer. Since as a god, Gruumsh can speak all languages (even though he likely would not deign to foul his mouth with *celestial* of all things -- eech!) if your character can speak the languages that Gruumsh can speak, then they can also speak all languages

Comment: Also not sure alignment equaling language is a reasonable logical jump. Actual citations of what Gruumsh speaks would be much better.

Comment: @NautArch, I agree with Thomas that he can speak whatever he wants. But I also think that choosing celestial which is pretty much anathema to what he stands for would be a dissonant choice.

Comment: I would like to tell you that my half-orc(a non-plot-related((as in is not directly linked to the plot)) PC for me) would not be able to speak all the languages unless they spent an extraordinary amount of time learning all those languages(He at max speaks 4)

Comment: If you would like to further discuss Gruumsh, [continue the discussion in the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145981/discussing-gruumsh).

Comment: Gruumsh lives in Acheron. Volo's p.82 says "orcs know that if they fight well and bring glory to their tribe, Gruumsh will call them home to the plane of Acheron. It is there in the afterlife where the chosen ones will join Gruumsh and his armies"

Comment: @MattVincent Neat! And Acheron isn't part of the Hells, it's just called an "infernal battlefield", but it is it's own plane (from my VERY brief research). Groody, if you can back this up more than just lawful evil = hells = infernal, then I think I have to keep my -1.

Comment: As a note, [the version of the tanarukk in *Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the Multiveerse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/2560937-tanarukk) has mostly the same languages listed, except it lists "plus any one language" instead of the Orc language.

Answer (score 20):

### It's a DM call – but Gruumsh lives in Acheron, where historically a lot of creatures spoke Infernal

*Volo's Guide to Monsters* (p. 82) says this about [orcs](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#OrcsTheGodsworn):

> [...] the orcs know that if they fight well and bring glory to their tribe, Gruumsh will call them home to the plane of Acheron. It is there in the afterlife where the chosen ones will join Gruumsh and his armies [...]

Historically, many of the inhabitants of "*the Infernal Battlefield of Acheron*" spoke Infernal (and I've found no 5e material conflicting with this). The Manual of the Planes (3.5e, p.124) stated that in addition to the spirit legions:

> Achaierai, devils, imps, fomorians rakshasas, dragons and yugoloths also inhabit Acheron

All of these except dragons & fomorians were explicitly listed as speaking infernal. *Maybe* it's because these beings can easily reach Acheron via the river styx, while Demons cannot (as they'd be stopped in Avernus by Devils).

Also fwiw (in editions 1 through 3.5): [Achaierai](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Achaierai) are the only known *true* natives to Acheron, and they have always *only* spoke infernal .

Answer (score 5):

### Gruumsh understands and speaks all languages.

The 3e supplement *Deities and Demigods* has a section on Gruumsh, which lists his special qualities (p. 71):

> **Special Qualities:** Orc traits, divine immunities, DR 67/+5, fire
> immunity, spontaneous casting of divine spells, *understand, speak, and read all languages*

Nothing in 5e has this level of specificity, so for this detail, you have to look to the older material.

So it doesn’t matter what your character speaks; Gruumsh can understand it. So instead of focusing on Gruumsh for this choice, focus instead on your background to find your third language.

Comment: Would this be appropriate to ***all*** editions 3.5e and up?

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 It hasn’t been retconned, so we can safely assume that Gruumsh hasn’t forgotten the languages he used to speak.